# Error: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature from using an array

Tags: typescript

I have an array which is a has a bunch of objects in it:

```
const standardStories = [
{
    name: 'Executive Summary',
    navLink: 'standard-stories/executive-summary',
    cardIndex: 0,
    storyBoxes: [
        {
            name: 'Chart Box',
            values: commonStdStories.chartBoxValue,
            graphics: commonStdStories.chartBoxGraphic,
        },
        {
            name: 'Financial Chart',
            values: commonStdStories.financialChartValue,
            graphics: commonStdStories.pieChart,
        },
        {
            name: 'Info Progress Bar',
            values: commonStdStories.progressBarValue,
            graphics: commonStdStories.progressBarGraphic,
        },
    ],
},
{
    name: 'High Cost Med',
    navLink: 'standard-stories/hcc-med',
    cardIndex: 2,
    storyBoxes: [
        {
            name: 'Info Progress Bar',
            values: commonStdStories.progressBarValue,
            graphics: commonStdStories.progressBarGraphic,
        },
        {
            name: 'Chart Box',
            values: commonStdStories.chartBoxValue,
            graphics: commonStdStories.chartBoxGraphic,
        },
        {
            name: 'HCC Table',
            value: commonStdStories.hccTable,
        },
    ],
},
{
    name: 'High Cost Rx',
    navLink: 'standard-stories/hcc-rx',
    cardIndex: 3,
    storyBoxes: [
        {
            name: 'Info Progress Bar',
            values: commonStdStories.progressBarValue,
            graphics: commonStdStories.progressBarGraphic,
        },
        {
            name: 'Chart Box',
            values: commonStdStories.chartBoxValue,
            graphics: commonStdStories.chartBoxGraphic,
        },
        {
            name: 'HCC Table',
            value: commonStdStories.hccTable,
        },
    ],
},
]
```

There are more, but you get the picture.

I am trying to use the storyBoxes like so:

```
standardStories.forEach(story => {
    **story.storyBoxes.forEach(storyBox => {})**
})
```

On the bolded line is where I am getting the error `[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature` Just wondering how to fix this so I can move on. Ideally I want to be able to loop through each story checking for each of the storyBoxes outlined in the storyBox for each story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this by changing the name in the storyBoxes array to `boxName` and making the `value` to be `values` like the others.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the type of the properties inside `commonStdStories`. If the types for the properties inside the `storyBoxes` are not consistent, the type of `storyBoxes` may end up being a union of arrays, which you can't use as an array because the methods end up being unions of the versions for each type in the union.

The simplest solution is to add a clear type for the constant, based on what I see inside the question, this would be a version:

```
interface IStory {

    name: string;
    navLink: string;
    cardIndex: number;
    storyBoxes: Array<{
        name: string;
        value?: string | number;
        values?: string| number; // Typo maybe ? do you want both value and values ?
        graphics?: string| number;
    }>;
}
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20commonStdStories%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20chartBoxValue%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20chartBoxGraphic%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20pieChart%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20financialChartValue%3A%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20progressBarGraphic%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20progressBarValue%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hccTable%3A0%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IStory%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20navLink%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cardIndex%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20storyBoxes%3A%20Array%3C%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values%3F%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graphics%3F%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3F%3A%20string%7C%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20standardStories%20%3A%20IStory%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Executive%20Summary'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20navLink%3A%20'standard-stories%2Fexecutive-summary'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cardIndex%3A%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20storyBoxes%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Chart%20Box'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values%3A%20commonStdStories.chartBoxValue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graphics%3A%20commonStdStories.chartBoxGraphic%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Financial%20Chart'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values%3A%20commonStdStories.financialChartValue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graphics%3A%20commonStdStories.pieChart%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Info%20Progress%20Bar'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values%3A%20commonStdStories.progressBarValue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graphics%3A%20commonStdStories.progressBarGraphic%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0D%0A%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'High%20Cost%20Med'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20navLink%3A%20'standard-stories%2Fhcc-med'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cardIndex%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20storyBoxes%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Info%20Progress%20Bar'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values%3A%20commonStdStories.progressBarValue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graphics%3A%20commonStdStories.progressBarGraphic%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Chart%20Box'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values%3A%20commonStdStories.chartBoxValue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graphics%3A%20commonStdStories.chartBoxGraphic%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'HCC%20Table'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20commonStdStories.hccTable%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0D%0A%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'High%20Cost%20Rx'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20navLink%3A%20'standard-stories%2Fhcc-rx'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cardIndex%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20storyBoxes%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Info%20Progress%20Bar'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values%3A%20commonStdStories.progressBarValue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graphics%3A%20commonStdStories.progressBarGraphic%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Chart%20Box'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values%3A%20commonStdStories.chartBoxValue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graphics%3A%20commonStdStories.chartBoxGraphic%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2)

Comment: the elements I am pointing to are all `element.all()`. So they are an array of element finders.

Comment: I did use the interface idea to ensure that I am doing them the same throughout. Thank you very much for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer the case in TypeScript 3.2. Now, if every member of a union is callable, the union itself is callable as well.